# Função para verificar se todos os elementos de uma array de variáveis são null

Tags: php, array, algoritmo, null

Suponhamos que eu tenha um *array* em que cada elemento deste *array* seja uma variável que armazena uma *string* dentro dela.

Exemplo:

```
error{
   [nome] : null;
   [sobrenome] : "sobrenome inválido";
   [estado] : null; }
```

Eu gostaria que o programa identificasse se todas as variáveis desse *array* são *null*, para então executar outra rotina.

```
error{
   [nome] : null;
   [sobrenome] : null;
   [estado] : null; }
```

Tentei rodar dessa forma, sem sucesso:

```
if(!empty($error)){
    $data["error"] = $error;
}else{
    //executa outra rotina
}
```

Comment: E por que precisa saber se todos são nulos?

Comment: O meu objetivo é: caso não tenha nenhuma ocorrência de erro (todas as variáveis deste array sejam null), ele desce para a etapa que faz a inclusão da informação cadastrada (capturando os inputs da minha tela de cadastro) no banco de dados. Estou usando um padrão RESTful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percorra o *array* e verifique com `is_null()` se o valor é nulo. Se não for já pode encerrar a execução já que basta um não sendo nulo para retorna falso. Só se ele percorrer todo o *array* sem achar um valor não nulo é que retorna verdadeiro. Aí é só usar este função no seu `if`.

```
function AllNull($error) {
    foreach ($error as $key => $value) if (!is_null( $value)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/AllNull.php).

Mas dependendo do que precise pode ser que a solução melhor seja outra compondo de outra forma.

Comment: Essa é a ideia. Vou testar e dou o feedback. =) De todo modo, marquei como melhor resposta. Obrigado!